# How to override CSS style with javascript?

Tags: javascript, css

I have an interactive page that changes td background color dynamically, with javascript. Without any style, this page works fine. As a style requirement, table background color should be black, and td background should be white. But due to cascade rules, dynamic changes have lower priority, so javascript is not able to override static style. How can I solve this? Thanks.

Sample 1:

```
cell.style.cssText = "background-color: gray;" // it works fine
```

Sample 2:

```
table {
  background-color:black;
}

td {
  background-color: white;
}
```

```
cell.style.cssText = "background-color: gray;" // it does not work anymore, even with "!important;"
```

Comment: You should use css classes. Use JS to set or remove the required class. Take a look at [how-can-i-change-an-elements-class-with-javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195951/how-can-i-change-an-elements-class-with-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inline styles override styles defined in `<style>` and it works even with dynamic styling using `cssText` (see my code example). Your problem is probably somewhere else, e.g. in the `cssText` value itself (it should be `background-color: gray;`, not just `gray`

```js
function foo() {
  document.getElementById("cell3").style.cssText = "background-color: green";
}
```

```css
table {
  background-color:black;
}

td {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
      <td>cell1</td>
      <td>cell2</td>
      <td id="cell3" onclick="foo()">cell3</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: Thanks, I fixed the "background-color: gray;". I see what I was doing wrong, I wanted to change the row background, but in the sample I put cell.